# Does the version admin workflow change when all users edit the SDE.DEFAULT version?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, maintenance

An esri blog article ([5 Best Practices SDE Maintenance](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/04/03/five-best-practices-for-maintaining-an-enterprise-geodatabase/)) states, when discussing updating statistics for an ArcSDE, "... in situations where all users are editing just the SDE.DEFAULT version [this is my case], you should just keep the statistics you collected before the compress. This will ensure that the query optimizer knows the delta tables are still active."

What does this mean? Does this mean I should not run the Compress tool prior to running the Analyze Dataset tool, but to do so only afterwards? This does not follow the maintenance workflow described here: [Recommended version administration workflow (ArcGIS Help)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000z7000000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once compressed, all the rows in the A&Don tables will be moved to the base table and the A&Ds will be empty. Building statistics at this point will cause the query optimizer to not be able to optimize the A&Ds (because they are empty). Meaning that even as they fill up during  the day as people are editing, the statistics are still configured to an empty table. This will cause your performance to degrade rapidly. Either follow that recommendation or run update statistics late morning or during lunch to get a new set of statistics with rows in the A&d tables.

Comment: I think you are suggesting I continue to compress, but to rebuild indexes and update statistics, respectively, after a few hours of edits have been made to the compressed SDE. Since I must compress, the statistics will eventually have to be configured to an empty table. Thank you for your response. Does it sound like I understood you correctly?

Comment: You can compress and Not update statistics. If you want to update statistics after compress, then be sure to update statistics again around mid-day to keep performance up. Dont forget to mark the question as answered if you are satisfied with this solution.